# Reference Security Group from other AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-security-group, pulumi

I have two AWS accounts named Sandbox and Dev. I have shared subnets of VPC created in the sandbox account with the dev account using AWS RAM. When I want to create an AWS load balancer in the dev account in shared subnets, I want to associate the security group with the load balancer I created in the sandbox account. Since I’m working on subnets belonging to the same VPC but shared across the account, I don’t think I need VPC peering. Is there any possible solution to share or reference the security group in this scenario

I tried making cross-account role in the Sandbox account and assumed role in the Dev account. I tried to make a resource, but it gives an error security group not found.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're implementing [something like this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/building-scalable-secure-multi-vpc-network-infrastructure/amazon-vpc-sharing.html), try to check the sharing VPC limitations section here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-sharing.html#vpc-share-limitations